# Extract value of the node with contains only English names

Tags: regex, xml, xpath

A sample XML file is:

```
<book category="lovestory">
    <title lang="en">Сумерки</title>
    <author>Stephanie Meyer</author>
   <year>2003</year>
   <price>50.07</price>
</book>
```

So far I have something like this XPath string:

> xpath.compile("/book[/title='[a-zA-z0-9]+']/author");

How can I get all authors of the English books? (I mean that titles are latin npt cyrillic) (This is Russian)

Comment: John le Carré is English. You can't assume that if something contains letters outside the range a-z then it's not English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath is almost correct.
Try to use following XPath:

```
//book//title[@lang='en']//..//author
```

**Explanation:**

You select all books which title is in english `//book//title[@lang='en']` and take the author of this book `//..//author`.

---

If you cannot rely on the lang attribute you can use regex (as you tried in your example). Following XPath uses a regular expression. The matches function is required which is available in XPath 2.0:

```
//book//title[matches(text(), '[a-zA-z0-9]+')]//..//author
```

---

Single slash `/` means node which is a direct child of the current.

Double slash `//` means any descendant node of the current node in the html tree which matches the locator.

Comment: Note that `[A-z]` matches more than `[a-zA-Z]` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret

Comment: There is also an XPath 1.0 solution: `//book[not(translate(title,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',''))]`